# Webpack 2: How to match package with mismatched @types?

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings, webpack-2

I'm trying to use webpack 2 to import SoundJS (one module of the createJS framework) into my typescript project.

in vendors.ts I have

```
import "soundjs";
```

along with several other working imports

The @types definitions imported using npm are named "soundjs", but the npm package "soundjs" is empty, so I have to use another npm package, named "createjs-soundjs" and this is causing a resolution error.

When I try to compile with webpack, I am getting the error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'soundjs' in '[path to the folder containing vendor.ts]'

How can I fix webpack 2 so that it resolves to the createjs-soundjs package?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix webpack 2 so that it resolves to the createjs-soundjs package?

You don't need to, because `createjs-soundjs` is not packaged as a module. This is from `soundjs-0.6.2.min.js` which is the entry point of the library.

`this.createjs=this.createjs||{},function()...`

which means the library will be available **globally in the browser context**.

You can also notice this from the `@types/soundjs` definition, where everything can be accessed globally through the namespaces

```
declare namespace createjs {
    export class AbstractPlugin {
        create(src: string, startTime: number, duration: number): AbstractSoundInstance;
        getVolume(): number;
        isPreloadComplete(src: string): boolean;
        ...
    }
}
```

So how we going to use this library with TypeScript?

```
import "createjs-soundjs";
console.log(createjs.RequestUtils.isImageTag("foo")); // false
```

You should get contextual-awareness (e.g. code completion) if `@types/soundjs` is already installed and included in the project.

[image]

Comment: Didn't really help with the issue I was having but I appreciate the time used to create a detailed reply so giving you the win :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'soundjs' in '[path to the folder containing vendor.ts]'

You should change `soundjs` to the package that actually exists : `createjs-soundjs` and then use this name consistently.

Comment: The names of the packages are defined by npm and automatically created in the node_modules folder. The typings are @types/soundjs, and the package is createjs-soundjs. If I were to do as you say, using npm for package management would no longer function. There must surely be a way for this to work without renaming npm packages?

Comment: Also doing this wouldn't be reflected on anyone elses machines since the node_modules package is normally .gitignore'd